# Meaning of Making it desolate

Tags: meaning-in-context, subjects

> Another ruined suitor, who periodically appears from Shropshire, and breaks out into efforts to address the Chancellor at the close of the day’s business, and who can by no means be made to understand that the Chancellor is legally ignorant of his existence **after** **making it desolate for a quarter** of a century, plants himself in a good place and keeps an eye on the Judge, ready to call out ‘My Lord!’ in a voice of sonorous complaint, on the instant of his rising.

'Bleak House' by Charles Dickens

In the bold part I think "it" refers to the suitor's existence. But I'm not sure who " making it desolate" is he himself the "suitor" or the Chancellor. And what does it actually mean to make an existence desolate? Is it simply to make a person's life miserable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, 'it' is the 'man from Shropshire's' existence, and his life has been made miserable by waiting for years for the court to make some progress with the case.

He doesn't know that the Chancellor is (officially) unaware of his existence, even though he has been making that existence desolate for the past 25 years.